# sudo ./byfn.sh generate command is throwing an error saying crypto-gen tool not found

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have been trying to install hyperledger fabric on raspberry PI and i have installed all the prerequisites for running up the sample byfn using fabcar samples but there's an error saying that "Docker composer is not able to pull the images" when i am trying to generate using the command ./byfn.sh generate[Docker-compose is causing an](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtBxP.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are no pre-built docker images for ARM on docker hub, neither are there any pre-built binaries for the ARM architecture either.

To run BYFN I needed a 4Gb system, I just cannot see a raspberry pi ever being able to run BYFN.

I believe other people have successfully compiled (from source) and run a single peer on a raspberry pi in the past, but as more capability is added to the Peer, it's system requirements will increase and it also requires storage to hold the complete blockchain.